# Получить доступ к папке

Tags: c#, .net, файловая-система

Нужно получить права на чтение и запись в папку, для работы с которой требуются административные права.

Или как сделать следующий код валидным:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:/System Volume Information");

foreach (var item in dir.GetDirectories())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.FullName);
}
```

Желательно что бы работало с `System Volume Information`

Следующий код не работает тоже:

```
[Flags]
enum MoveFileFlags
{
    MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING = 0x00000001,
    MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED = 0x00000002,
    MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x00000004,
    MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x00000008,
    MOVEFILE_CREATE_HARDLINK = 0x00000010,
    MOVEFILE_FAIL_IF_NOT_TRACKABLE = 0x00000020
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, MoveFileFlags dwFlags);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"D:/System Volume Information";

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    MoveFileEx(path, path + "2", MoveFileFlags.MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING);

    string msg = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;

    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ага, я нашёл, как Far это делает.

Он не просто запускает процесс от имени администратора (на самом деле, дочерний процесс, с которым связывается через pipe). Этот самый дочерний процесс, будучи запущенным от имени администратора, имеет право затребовать себе привилегии Backup и Restore (вот [официальный метод, как сделать такое на чистом WinAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/setting-the-backup-and-restore-privileges)). Что он и делает. Имея эти привилегии, дочерний процесс [может делать всё](http://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?t=6083).

Мораль: вы можете ограничить в правах административный процесс, но он может снять ваши ограничения.

---

Для читателей, вот работающий код: (*разумеется*, вы должны добавить манифест, как указано в ответе @Dmitry)

```
class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        using (var outf = File.CreateText(@"D:\dirlist.txt"))
        {
            if (!RequestSeBackupPrivilege())
            {
                outf.WriteLine("Cannot request privilege: ");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                string path = @"D:\System Volume Information";
                var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                foreach (var item in dir.GetFileSystemInfos())
                    outf.WriteLine(item.FullName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                outf.WriteLine("Exception:");
                outf.Write(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    static bool RequestSeBackupPrivilege()
    {
        LUID luid;

        if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeBackupPrivilege", out luid))
            return false;

        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES_SINGLE tp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES_SINGLE
        {
            PrivilegeCount = 1,
            Luid = luid,
            Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED
        };

        IntPtr hToken;
        return
            OpenProcessToken(
                GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, out hToken) &&
            AdjustTokenPrivileges(
                hToken, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) &&
            (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED);
    }

    const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
    const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
    const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
    const int ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED = 1300;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES_SINGLE
    {
        public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
        public LUID Luid;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct LUID
    {
        public uint LowPart;
        public int HighPart;
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(
        string lpSystemName, string lpName, out LUID lpLuid);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
        IntPtr ProcessHandle, UInt32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES_SINGLE newst,
        int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);
}
```

Определения структур данных взяты на pinvoke.net.

Comment: Великолепно! Кстати, вот тут есть примеры на C#: [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/AdjustTokenPrivileges.html) (рекомендую *C# Sample Code 2*).

Comment: @Dmitry: Ага, я как раз пытался импортировать [этот код](https://github.com/giuliano108/SeBackupPrivilege/blob/master/SeBackupPrivilegeUtils/Utils.cs).

Comment: Я взял вышеуказанный пример целиком, заменил только вызов на `Privileges.EnablePrivilege(SecurityEntity.SE_BACKUP_NAME);` и все заработало.

Comment: Способ с привилегиями использует QDir.

Comment: Добавил работающий код.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А что такое QDir? (Извини мою неграмотность.) Это вот [эта штука](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Dir)?

Comment: @VladD, да. http://softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir

Comment: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?t=43745&f=32#p6760504

Answer (score 6):

Насколько я помню, этот фолдер не залочен, а требует повышенных привилегий администратора.

Чтобы повысить привилегии вашего приложения, добавьте в проект файл манифеста (выполнив Project -> Add New Item -> "Application Manifest File"), а в нем откорректируйте значение узла `requestedExecutionLevel` следующим образом:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: @AntonKomyshan т.е. запрос UAC отображается, приложение повышается до админа, но прав все равно не хватает? у меня решение от Dmitry вполне работает.

Comment: Честно говоря, у меня тоже не работает. Хотя тому же Far'у вполне хватает повышения до админа, чтобы прочитать эту папку.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, там нужен не администратор, а Local System.

Comment: @VladD, поподробней, пожалуйста, и если можно на C# :-)

Comment: Ну, я посмотрел, какие права есть на этот каталог у различных пользователей. Например, у администратора вроде бы нет прав на чтение. Хотя администратор в силах _добавить_ себе эти права. // Сейчас гляну в исходники Far'а.

Comment: @VladD зависит от версии windows, судя по всему. у меня обычное консольное приложение под админом нормально читает содержимое SVI

Comment: @PashaPash: А какая версия?

Comment: @VladD Windows 10

Comment: @z668 и вы туда же. ну сколько можно вестись на эту желтизну. винда собрает примерно столько, сколько любая мобильная операционка. что-то я не вижу призывов отказаться от android/iphone. или от хрома. или хотя бы от gmail.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28831/discussion-between-pashapash-and-z668).

Answer (score 2):

VladD прав. Это защищенная системная папка, доступ к которой осуществляется при помощи прав Local System. Вам нужно запустить свое приложение от Local System, сделать это можно следующими способами:

- Использовать планировщик задач (TaskScheduler).
- Написать службу и запустить приложение из нее.
- Внедриться в какой-нибудь LocalSystem-процесс и оттуда запустить свою
  программу.
- Использовать psexec (Sysinternals) с ключом -s.