# Как скопировать файлы из одной папки в другую ( с идентичным именем папки )?

Tags: c#

Из пункта **А** cкопировать идентичную папку (*с файлами внутри*) в пункт **Б**

Нужно создать точную копию папки в свою папку, делаю это таким путём:

```
foreach (var dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Users\Robot\AppData\Roaming\AdbDriverInstaller", "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
{  
 Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace("C:\Users\Robot\AppData\Roaming\AdbDriverInstaller", "C:\\MyFolder\"));
}
```

В папке `C:\\MyFolder\` создаётся точная именная папка `AdbDriverInstaller`

Как мне скопировать все файлы с этой идентичной папки (`C:\Users\Robot\AppData\Roaming\AdbDriverInstaller`) в мою папку `"C:\\MyFolder\AdbDriverInstaller"`?

Проблема решена с помощью [Данной темы.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654232/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9?rq=1)

Comment: [How to: Copy Directories](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories)

Comment: Вы пробовали когда нибудь выводить список всех файлов? Если нет, то попробуйте, забавное занятие. Суть проста, вы должны воспользоваться рекурсией (вызов метода из самого себя). То есть создаем метод, который будет делать три действия 1. Создание новой папки. 2. Циклом копирование всех файлов из папки "а" в папку "б". Ну и 3. Еще один цикл, который пробегает по всем директориям в папки "а" и вызывает на каждую итерацию заново этот метод (который опять создает папку, копирует файлы и ищет директории...). [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146021/copy-all-files-in-directory#7146097).

Comment: Проблема в том что вот я создал идентичную папку в своей директории, а как скопировать я знаю, а вот как задать именно в эту идентичную папку не знаю ( эта папка постоянно рандомное имя делает в конце).