# Как узнать и поменять владельца файла?

Tags: c#

Написал код, который чудесно узнает текущего владельца файла, но никак не хочет его менять на какого-либо другого. 
Судя по MSDN, все прописано так, как надо. Но не работает.

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace GET_SET_OWNER
{
    class Program
    {
        public static bool GetOwner(string File_UNC)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Текущий владелец:");
            var File_Security = File.GetAccessControl(File_UNC);
            var SID = File_Security.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            Console.WriteLine(SID);

            var Owner = SID.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
            Console.WriteLine(Owner);
            return true;
        }

        public static bool SetOwner(string File_UNC)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Задаем нового владельца..." + 
                Environment.NewLine);
            var New_Owner = new NTAccount("Home", "Браток");
            var File_Security = File.GetAccessControl(File_UNC);
            File_Security.SetOwner(New_Owner);

            try
            {
                File.SetAccessControl(File_UNC, File_Security);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string File_UNC = @"D:\1.txt";
            bool res_1 = false,
                 res_2 = false,
                 res_3 = false;

            res_1 = GetOwner(File_UNC);
            res_2 = SetOwner(File_UNC);
            res_3 = GetOwner(File_UNC);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", res_1, res_2, res_3);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Есть у кого-нибудь идеи?
Функция **SetOwner** при каждой попытке изменить текущего владельца выдает **System.InvalidOperationException: Идентификатору безопасности запрещено быть владельцем данного объекта** и возвращает **false**. При этом, если менять владельца файла на текущего, то есть, например,(Пользователь) - это текущий владелец, меняем на (Пользователь), то функция проделывает свою работу и возвращает **true**.

В случае, когда текущий владелец файла **Браток**, программа справляется с задачей и меняет владельца на любого другого в системе.
То есть сменить владельца с **Браток** на **Пользователь** - это не проблема.
Проблема в том, чтобы провести операцию по смене владельца с **Пользователь** на **Браток**.

Comment: А какой результат возвращает `SetOwner`?

Comment: права, на смену владельца нужны права. В большинстве случаев - права администратора.

Comment: @E.Zubkov: А что именно она возвращает, `false` или `true`, нам разрешается угадать?

Comment: @VladD я не понимаю вопроса. В случае успешного изменения владельца возвращается **true**, иначе выявляется **exсeption** и возвращается **false**.

Comment: В вашем то случае возвращается true или false?

Comment: @E.Zubkov: Вы говорите, что у вас, цитирую, «код ... никак не хочет его менять» владельца файла. Это ужасное описание проблемы, если честно. У вас могло быть выброшено исключение, могло вернуться `false`, могло вернуться `true`, и все эти случаи — разные. Для того, чтобы понять, в чём конкретно проблема, я пытался выяснить, отрабатывает ли в вашем случае `SetOwner` успешно. Но вы почему-то сопротивляетесь решению вашей собственной проблемы.

Comment: @VladD Ваш вопрос я понял буквально, и объяснил, что возвращается в случае работы функции.

Comment: @E.Zubkov: Окей, тогда давайте я и на ваш вопрос отвечу буквально. Да, идеи есть.

Comment: @E.Zubkov что в принципе возвращает функция можно и в документации прочитать, что конкретно у вас она возвращает во время работы? так понятнее? И еще убедитесь что вы правильно задаете нового владельца, в том смысле что новый владелец не может быть с потолка, это должен быть один из зарегистрированых в системе пользователей

Comment: с учетом правки вопроса - проверяйте что пытаетесь задать существующего пользователя

Comment: и обратите внимание SAMAccountName и DisplayName не взаимозаменяеы в общем случае

Comment: вы руками это сделать с файлом можете? если нет, то и программа не сможет. Проверяйте

Comment: ну вот теперь есть о чем думать. ну почему каждый раз нужно по биту информацию вытягивать...< ушел читать доки по теме>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хорошие вопросы редкость.

Проблема вот в чем. Для того чтобы стать владельцем объекта файловой системы, пользователь должен иметь право становиться владельцем либо быть администратором. Если условия выполнены - пользователь может назначать себя и только себя владельцем объекта ФС.

Для того чтобы назначить владельцем другого пользователя - нужны права на восстановление объектов ФС. По умолчанию эти права отключены даже для администратора. Собственно поэтому у вас и получается переназначить владельца на себя и не получается наоборот.

Собственно решение проблемы - назначить процессу или пользователю, от чьего имени запускается процесс, права на восстановление объектов ФС.

В сети на эту тему информация 5-7 летней давности, но похоже что до сих пор ни чего не поменялось и .NET не предоставляет средств для получения этих прав, но можно воспользоваться средствами WinAPI. Одно из таких решений на которое часто ссылаются можно посмотреть в [блоге salamandersoft](http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/setting-the-owner-of-files-and-directories-in-c/) а также в ответе **@VladD** [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448383/198316)

Comment: @VladD как я мог забыть про это обсуждение, хоть и не участвовал в нем, но внимательно следил. Каюсь, добавил ссылку.

Comment: Спасибо! (_покраснел_)

Comment: Спасибо за подробное пояснение! Буду исправлять проблему.