# Куда сохранять временные файлы не имея прав администратора?

Tags: c#

Логика программы устроена следующим образом:

1. мы имеем файл внутри проекта, при необходимости программа делает
   экземпляр файла в папке **user/AppData/Local/Temp**
2. полученный путь передаёт в качестве аргумента процессу
   (`Process.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;`)
3. после работы с файлом я его удалял

Когда я тестировал программу - запускал .exe. Из под визуал студии всё было хорошо, но когда я создал установщик моей программы, установил и запустил, оказалось, что без прав администратора программа не может создавать файлы в папке Temp.

Запустил с правами администратора, всё заработало, далее добавил код, перед запуском формы включить запрос на права администратора и если прав нет то не включать программу.

Все работает но я начал рассуждать и решил что что-то не так. 100% будет ситуация, что админских прав не будет у пользователя.
Соответвенно всё застопается на создании файла в папке Temp.

Подскажите мне как исправить эту ситуацию, то есть мне надо будучи не имя прав администратора запустить программу которая сможет создавать файл (желательно на основном диске, желательно в папке темп, ибо может и не быть разбивки на С и Д диски) и удалять его.
**Код:**
**Поиск папки Temp**

```
string pathTemp = Path.GetTempPath();
```

**Код создания файла в папке Temp**

```
byte[] array = Properties.Resources.fileForProg;
name = "тратата.data";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathTemp + "/" + name, FileMode.Create);
fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length);//именно здесь будет крэш не имея админских прав
fs.Close();
```

**Запуск процесса**

```
procForProg = new Process();
procForProg.StartInfo.Arguments = pathTemp + "/" + name;
procForProg.StartInfo.FileName = "prog.exe";
procForProg.Start();
```

Еще пару вопросов:
Можно ли как то запихнуть prog.exe сразу в оперативку, то есть сейчас я имею на жестком диске экземпляр .exe, и через Process открываю его, потом программа естественно сама загружается в оперативку, я бы хотел держать .exe внутри своей программы и загружать .exe сразу в оперативку. Чтобы не иметь на жестком диске экземпляра .exe.

Comment: Вопрос номер раз - а почему вы используете символ '/' в качестве разделителя? Стандартный виндовый путь использует вроде как вот такой символ - "\" (обратный слэш: http://savepic.ru/12132900.png . Но это и не важно, потому как **лучше использовать `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`**.   Относительно запуска файла из массива байт я уже ответил ниже, равно как и дополнил ответ насчет прав и поисков временной папки.

Comment: ох, сейчас переварю всю инфу и отпишусь о результатах)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл проблему))
На деле я не вытаскивал файл из ресурсов проекта (это я для понимания задачи сказал так), а собирал(по байтам) из 5-ти файлов в один файл и создаю его экземпляр с папке temp.
Эти 5 файлов находятся рядом с приложением, то есть после установки на диске "C"(к примеру не имея админских прав обычный юзер не сможет удалить файлы/программу).
Мм, скину немного кода
В коде из 5ти файлов, которые лежат в той же папке что и .exe, создать 1 файл и сохранить его в папку temp.
Данный код должен работать у пользователя не имеющего админские права

```
string[] tempNameFile = {"code1.ff","code2.ff","code3.ff","code4.ff","code5.ff"};//список файлов, они находились в папке с .exe 
string path = Path.GetTempPath();//находим папку темп юзера
string nameFile = "file.data";//название файла

using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path + nameFile, FileMode.Create))
{
    foreach (string tempName in tempNameFile)//проходим по массиву с названиями файлов
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream tempFileStream = new FileStream(tempName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                long length = tempFileStream.Length;
                for (long i = 0; i < length; ++i)
                {
                    int temp = tempFileStream.ReadByte();
                    fstream.WriteByte((byte)temp);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Переустановите приложение.", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
    fstream.Close();
}
```

Вся проблема была в **отсутствии параметра FileAccess.Read при обращении к файлу на диске "С"** из под обычного юзера (а эта инфа может быть полезна  )
**Выводы:**

- Не имя админских прав можно сохранять файлы в папке temp
- для обращения к файлу находящегося на диске С добавить параметр
  **FileAccess.Read**

Comment: Вывод номер два должен быть таким: *не выпендриваться и использовать метод `File.OpenRead` для чтения*. :)

Comment: Кстати, у вас ошибка в коде создания временного файла. Если такой файл уже был, а вы попытаетесь перезаписать его более короткой версией - в конце останется мусор. Используйте `fstream.SetLength(fstream.Position)` перед закрытием.

Comment: Кстати, еще один недочет - не надо писать `Close()` если используете `using`. Нет смысла закрывать файл два раза.

Comment: И третий недочет - вы забыли про метод `CopyTo` у потока. Цикл не нужен.

Comment: спасибо за правки, если вас не затруднит, напишите Вашу версию, я с радостью её рассмотрю и использую

Comment: Не, не буду я вам код писать. Даже если вы будете его "с радостью использовать". Я просто перечислил те места, где у вас могут возникнуть грабли в будущем (кроме Close, второе закрытие влияет только на красоту кода).

Comment: Оки-доки  
На счёт CopyTo он по порядку будет записывать байты? мне важна последовательность,иначе хэш код полученного файла не будет совпадать с оригиналом)

Comment: А как вы себе представляете копирование не по порядку? И зачем вообще такое копирование может кому-нибудь понадобиться?

Comment: ммм, не понимаю. Если вам интересно то опишите что непонятно, я постараюсь объяснить.  
может выясниться что я занимаюсь оверхэдом и можно сделать всё куда легче))

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, по порядку ли CopyTo записывает байты. Если у вас возник такой вопрос - значит, вы видите какую-то альтернативу. Как вы ее себе представляете?

Answer (score 4):

Есть метод [Path.GetTempPath();](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx), который возвращает путь к временной папке **текущего пользователя**, следовательно, у пользователя **должны быть** (но не обязаны, да) по-умолчанию права записи туда. Но этот метод проверяет существование переменных среды в следующем порядке и использует *первый найденный путь*:

- Путь, указанный в переменной среды TMP.
- Путь, указанный в переменной среды TEMP.
- Путь, указанный в переменной среды USERPROFILE.
- Каталог Windows.

Если вдруг поведение по-умолчанию для пользователя изменено (например, явно выставлен запрет на запись в папку Temp в какой-то из этих локаций), то можно:

1. Попробовать запросить права на чтение и запись в эту папку. Это, разумеется, уже [другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448240/222168), но вариант ответа на него [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448383/222168).
2. Посмотреть вручную другие пути из переменных окружения, например, если нет прав на папку **%user%/AppData/Local/Temp**, то смотреть существование папки и права на неё, если она указана в переменной окружения Tmp, Temp, Windows/Temp. В общем, немного доделать работу за `GetTempPath()`. Посмотреть содержимое переменной окружения можно, например, так: `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")`.

---

**UPDATE:**
Для проверки прав пользователя на запись в временные файлы сделал вот такое демо-приложение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код консольного приложения (C# 6.0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

......

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Проверка прав на запись в временные папки.\nver. -1.0, специально для ru.stackoverflow.com");
    //Список директорий для проверки прав:
    List<string> DirList = new List<string>();

    //Временная переменная:
    string path = string.Empty;

    //Создаем список директорий для проверки:
    path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");

    //Если директория, прочитанная из переменной окружения существует - добавляем её в список.
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        DirList.Add(path);
    }

    //Повторяем процесс...
    path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP");
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        DirList.Add(path);
    }

    //И еще раз....
    path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR");
    path = path.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Temp";
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        DirList.Add(path);
    }

    //Теперь папка для пользователя...
    path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
    path = path.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Temp";
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        DirList.Add(path);
    }

    //Выводим список полученных директорий:
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,DirList));
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Вычисляем домен и имя пользователя
    string DomainAccountName = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
    Console.WriteLine("Проверка прав для пользователя "+DomainAccountName);

    //Для каждой из папок проверяем права
    foreach (var dir in DirList)
    {
        //Получаем список правил доступа к папке для пользователей:
        DirectorySecurity dirACL = Directory.GetAccessControl(dir, AccessControlSections.Access);
        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = dirACL.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
        //Для каждого полученного правила выполняем проверку:
        foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
        {
            //Если мы нашли совпадение правила для нашего пользователя...
            if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(DomainAccountName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                //...то пытаемся привести правило к типу FileSystemAccessRule и проверить права доступа,
                //причем вместо WriteData можно использовать другие значения, если нужно, например, 
                //CreateFiles.
                //Саму проверку можно было выполнить, например, так:
                //if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData) > 0) 
                if ((rule as FileSystemAccessRule).FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.WriteData))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DomainAccountName} может писать в {dir}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DomainAccountName} НЕ может писать в {dir}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER для выхода...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Можно, было, конечно, пойти путем попытки создания файла и отлова Exceptions, но этот вариант просто показался мне интереснее.

**Единственное и крайне важное - нужно помнить, что проверка, оно хорошо, но вполне может случиться так, что проверили и нужные права есть, потом пытаемся писать что-то, а права поменялись!**

---

Что же касается запуска приложения из массива байт, то можете попробовать сделать так:

```
//Массив байт с запускаемым приложением.
byte[] exeBuffer = ......Тут вы инициализируете массив байт, который есть ваше запускаемое приложение, например, читаете из ресурсов.

//Загружаем
Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(exeBuffer);

//Выполняем
exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null); //Запуск без параметров.
```

Опять же, если наш EXE - исполняемый файл, созданный непонятно в чём, где и когда, то высока вероятность ошибки **BadImageFormatException**. Причина этого, вероятнее всего, в том, что компилятор (или иное средство генерации EXE) при создании удаляет адреса переадресации или раздел .reloc из исполняемого файла.

Comment: дада) код что я использую  
private static string path = Path.GetTempPath();  
using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path + "/" + name, FileMode.Create))  
спасибо, сейчас займусь изучением ваших ссылок

Comment: 1. Можно ли запросить сам код?
2. Вы передаете путь к папке Temp для чужого процесса, так? Возможно, _этот_ процесс не имеет прав к папке Temp, а не ваша программа?

Comment: Да, .exe который я запускаю через процесс это купленная программа, я имею права её распространять. Сам .exe я храню внутри программы, далее я создаю экземпляр в папке Темп. Вот на создании и происходит ошибка, самой программе не нужны права админа для работы. Мой код прям суда скинуть? не проблема, сейчас только уберу всё лишнее)) Ммм, а подскажите как делать разныв строки, не получается, я пытался двойной пробел, пытался ставить <br/>, не получается. Спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: Код лучше поместить в оригинал вопроса. Насчет строк - в комментариях форматирование [несколько иное](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), чем при публикации вопросов/ответов. И благодарить пока не за что еще )

Comment: Сделайте разрыв в 2 строки ). Чуть выше в комментарии я дал ссылку на справку по редактору, что он поддерживает в вопросах/ответах и комментариях, так же можно нажать кнопку "?" в редакторе, а еще когда набираете ответ или задаете вопрос, то в интерфейсе ниже формы редактирования есть превью, как это будет выглядеть в конечном виде.

Comment: Попробовал Ваш способ с использованием ассэмблера  
Выдаёт ошибку  
"была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат."
винда у меня х64, сборку делал на х64
<img src="http://s017.radikal.ru/i432/1611/c2/55abd8e8eb5b.png" width="300" height="300">

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48326/discussion-between-blackwitcher-and--).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48348/discussion-between-blackwitcher-and--).

Comment: в общем
если запускаю программу, скомпилированную с помощью ВС, всё запускается, в папке темп я могу создавать файлы
если я делаю из программы уставщика, в той же ВС, то без админских прав прога не хочет создавать в папке темп файлы